# bind to click event to external content when using innerHTML angular

Tags: javascript, angular

Is it possible to bind to an event which is from external content. Content is brought in via `innerHTML`

I have the below code whereby I grab external content and display it within my app.  I'm trying to listen to an onClick event for the `<a>` tag. The `<a>` is a route redirect. The listen should reside within my app as I want do some other things before routing to a new route.

I've tried setting a handleClick function but I don't think this is the correct way to do it.

I also thought maybe using a `ElementRef` - in this case `#view` but would jquery light be better in this case.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'overview-details',
  template: `
    <h2>{{ title }}</h2>
    <div #view [innerHTML]="regCode | sanitizeHtml"></div>
  `
})

ngOninit() {
    this.regcode = `
        <div>
            <h1>RegCode Content</h1>
            <a class="link" (click)="handleClick()">Link</a>
        </div>
    `;
}

//within controller
handleClick(){
    // do some stuff
    // then route
    router.navigate([somewhere....]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked out the following in the end.

I added the `(click)` to the `div` and also added a `data-route` to the `<a>` and can use `event.target.dataset.route` to get the value.

Just incase anyone else has similar issues

```
@Component({
  selector: 'overview-details',
  template: `
   <h2>{{ title }}</h2>
   <div (click)="handleClick($event)" [innerHTML]="regCode | sanitizeHtml"></div>
   `
})

ngOninit() {
   this.regcode = `
      <div>
          <h1>RegCode Content</h1>
          <a class="link" data-route="0">Link</a>
      </div>
  `;
}

handleClick(event: any) {
    console.log('fire', event.target.dataset.route);
    if (event.target.dataset.route == 0) {
       router.navigate([somewhere....]);
    } esle {
       router.navigate([somewhereElse....]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular doesn't process HTML added with `[innerHTML]="..."` or any other way. Bindings like `(click)="..."` work **only** when added statically to a comopnents template.

You can use

```
constructor(private elRef:ElementRef) {}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('a.link').addEventListener('click', this.handleClick.bind(this));
}
```